# What is the source of this saying about allotment of words?

Tags: sources-mekorot, speech-talking

What is the source of the saying that each human being is born with a certain allotment of words to utter?

Comment: Hi Phil. Why do you think there is a source for that saying in Judaism?

Comment: I have edited your question to add a tag and to make the title include something to hint to the actual question. You can feel free to change this or make further [edit]s.

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya Phil. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: BTW My grandmother told this to me when I was perhaps 4 or 5 in an effort to keep me quiet. It worked (but only temporarily).

Comment: If that's your reason for thinking this is a Jewish belief please edit that into the question, not leave it in a comment. Comments are ephemeral by design and may be deleted at any time. Important info should be in the question post itself

Comment: This is not a delicate question. The 2 links you referenced are only about whether the concept is true and what is the source to the concept. And what is regarded a correct is the answer from Gershon Gold, who only quotes late Acharonim. They are clearly not the source. The Acharonim are not the source, meaning they didn't originate the idea. All the sources in my answer are Rishonim or earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a quick check and found a discussion on this [elsewhere](https://www.theyeshivaworld.com/coffeeroom/topic/limited-number-of-words-in-life). There, someone points to [this](https://torah.org/torah-portion/ravfrand-5762-vaera/) webpage. [Further](https://www.theyeshivaworld.com/coffeeroom/topic/limited-number-of-words-in-life#post-915321) on in the discussion, someone points to a source, but the Hebrew doesn't carry over in his post so the source is not written in.

Comment: From the context of what is written in the last link you bring, it's from _Midrash ha-Gadol_ on _Shemot_ 7:8-9, and I think he is referring to what it says [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=33185&pgnum=65) , starting on line 5.

Answer (score -3):

It is taken from Amos 4:13 and follows the commentary of Radak, Metzudat David and Ibn Ezra to the posuk.

Ibn Ezra:

> **מה שיחו- מה רצונו לעשות** והוא יהפך השחר עליכם וישוב חשך, כמו: ארץ עיפתה כמו אופל וידרוך על במותי ארצכם ולא תראוהו. **ויפת אמר: יוצר הרים שהם נראים ובורא רוחות בגויות *ומגיד לאדם מה שיחו מה שישיח בלבו.*** ועל דרך המפרשים: כי השם יעשה כרצונו דבר והפכו, על כן אם תשובו אליו - יהפך הגזירות הרעות לטובות.

G-d tells a person what his speech is and **what he *will say in his heart.*** The Yafat Toar commentary to Shemot Rabbah which Ibn Ezra quotes is found in Shemot Rabbah, parshah 5:8, beginning with the words "אלא מהו כל המופתים"

Radak:

> וכן **הוא מגיד לאדם מה שיחו מה ענינו** ומעשיו ולא יחשב שאינו רואה אותם כמו שהיו אומרים הכופרים אין ה' רואה אותנו **כי הנה הוא מגיד לכם מעשיכם ע"י נביאו, שיחו, בצר"י אתם ידעתם את האיש ואת שיחו בחיר"ק ושניהם ענין האדם ומעשיו:**

G-d tells a person what his speech and actions are through His prophets.

Metzudot David:

> כי הנה יוצר הרים. כי הנה ה׳ הוא היוצר את ההרים והוא הבורא את הרוח והכל שלו ובידו **והוא מגיד לאדם *מה יהיה דבורו* כי יודע הוא תעלומות לב**

G-d tells a person what his speech ***will be...****emphasized text*

See also the comment of Ramban to Shemot 7:3 which expresses the same sentiment.

> **ואני אקשה את לב פרעה** אמרו במדרש רבה (שמו''ר ה ו) ***גילה לו שהוא עתיד לחזק את לבו* בעבור לעשות בו הדין**, תחת שהעבידם בעבודה קשה. ועוד שם (יג ד) כי אני הכבדתי את לבו (להלן י א), אמר רבי יוחנן מכאן פתחון פה למינין לומר לא היתה ממנו שיעשה תשובה. אמר רבי שמעון בן לקיש יסתם פיהם של מינין, אלא אם ללצים הוא יליץ (משלי ג לד), מתרה בו פעם ראשונה ושניה ושלישית ואינו חוזר בו והוא נועל בו דלת מן התשובה כדי לפרוע ממנו מה שחטא. כך פרעה הרשע, כיון ששגר הקב''ה אצלו חמש פעמים ולא השגיח על דבריו, אמר לו הקב''ה אתה הקשית את ערפך והכבדת את לבך, הריני מוסיף לך טומאה על טומאתך:

G-d reveals to His prophet, Moshe, ***what will be*** and ***what the actions of Pharaoh will be***. G-d knows beforehand what a persons actions are.

It is also brought in Midrash HaGadol to parshat VaEira in Sefer Shemot 7:9 (Volume 3, pp. 113-114 of the Mossad HaRav Kook edition)

[image][[image]][[image]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUlLs.jpg)

Comment: Ibn Ezra doesn't say that. Neither does Metzudot David. Haven't checked Radak, but have low expectations.

Comment: Why don't you just quote the cited commentaries in your answer, and show how each of them says that "each human being is born with a certain allotment of words to utter" (from the question). Otherwise, I don't see it either.

Comment: Don't just throw "Amos 4:13" - please cite the source and show how it is connected to the question

Comment: @TamirEvan Please look over the actual citations now. A vote to reopen would be appreciated.

Comment: @AlBerko Please look over the actual citations now. A vote to reopen would be appreciated.

Comment: Yaacov You quoted the sources but you forgot to include "how it is connected to the question". Most of these sources don't answer the question.

Comment: @YaacovDeane For the record, the question's duplicate status is not determined by the correctness/incorrectness of your answer. It is determined by whether the question has already been asked and answered. If you think that the answer on the already existing question is wrong, the correct procedure is to downvote/comment if you want, and post your own answer on that question.

Comment: I still don't see how these commentators on Amos 4:13 (Radak, Metzudat David, and Ibn Ezra), or the Ramban on Shemot 7:3, are interpreting the verses as referring to "a certain allotment of words to utter" that a person is born with, as the question asks for. In fact, I read Radak to understand _Seycho_ / _Sicho_ as meaning a man's 'essence' and  'actions', not his 'speaking'.

Comment: @TamirEvan the commentators are not saying different, disagreeing things. They are all expressing the same concept in different, often abbreviated, words. Look at the Midrash HaGadol, which is the most explicit. Then review what the others are saying. It’s all consistent and is dealing with a basic element of Jewish belief. How G-d can know every detail of creation before the creation occurs. Where is free choice? Is everything predetermined? But the principle is that the end is wedged in the beginning, and the beginning in the end.